# Do I need to deploy Asp.Net Console Application connected with .Net Core Web API project?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, connection, console-application

I have a .net console application which is doing some stuff for IIS. I am calling this console application with a button click from View side which is working fine.

Now I want to deploy the project. Do I need to deploy the connected console application (or its .exe file). If yes, How ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to deploy your console application to server as well.

Instead of calling your console application via button from your app view, simply automate it by converting it into a windows service. You can create windows service by:

1. Converting your **ConsoleApplication (.NET Framework) to Windows Services (.NET Framework)** project. Then create and installer setup package and install via that setup package on your server.
2. Build your solution in release mode to generate .exe and then by using **NSSM tool** to convert your .exe into a windows service.

Comment: Hello @asmak9, 
Thanks for your kind response.
Yes, we can do that by creating a Windows Service, but that's not an option in my case.

Comment: Okay then then you need to place your exe into content folder, so when you click the button from view it is accessible.

Comment: Yeah, tried that one.
Placed the exe in the root folder and give that button this path and it seems to be worked. 
Thanks